# How to Add Text Inputs val() Into JSON Array

Tags: jquery, json

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/ahh8vu3n/2/) and let me how I can Add/ Insert the `data` into the JSON array Users?

```
"users":[
    {"user":"John", "age":36, "grade":"C", "mark":88 }, 
    {"user":"Rose", "age":28, "grade":"B", "mark":90 }, 
    ....
]

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addtoJSON").click(function () {
        var user = $("#user").val();
        var age = $("#age").val();
        var grade = $("#grade").val();
        var mark = $("#mark").val();
        // alert(user);
        var data = 'name=' + user + '&age=' + age + '&grade=' + grade + '&mark=' + mark;
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
var dataArr = [];
var data = JSON.stringify({  // use JSON.stringify to convert object to JSON
    name: user,
    age: age,
    grade: grade,
    mark: +mark
});
dataArr.push(data);
alert(data); // well formed JSON
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ahh8vu3n/3/)

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for reply but how I can add each new series of input into the data?

Comment: I mean I need to create Array of JSON object

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add new `Object` to "users" `Object`'s array:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahh8vu3n/4/).

```
var fullData =
{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "user": "John",
            "age": 36,
            "grade": "C",
            "mark": 88
        }, 
        {
            "user": "Rose",
            "age": 28,
            "grade": "B",
            "mark": 90
        }
    ]
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#addtoJSON").click(function()
    {
        var user = $("#user").val();
        var age = parseInt($("#age").val());
        var grade = $("#grade").val();
        var mark = parseInt($("#mark").val());
        var data = 
        {
            name: user,
            age: age,
            grade: grade,
            mark: mark
        };
        fullData.users.push(data);
        console.log(fullData);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fullData));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help -:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var jsonArg1 = new Object();
  var jsonArg2 = new Object();
   $("#addtoJSON").click(function () {
     jsonArg1.user = $("#user").val();
     jsonArg1.age = $("#age").val();
     jsonArg1.grade = $("#grade").val();
     jsonArg1.mark = $("#mark").val();

     jsonArg12.users = jsonArg1;

     var pluginArrayArg = new Array();
     pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg12);
     pluginArray = (JSON.stringify(pluginArrayArg))
     console.log(pluginArray);
  });
});
```